# Why is pandas' indexing so slow? How to make it faster?

Tags: python, pandas

Running this code shows the difference in speed between pandas and a regular python list:

```
ser = pd.Series(range(100))
lst = ser.tolist()

for _ in range(10):
    pandas_time = 0
    list_time = 0
    for _ in range(100000):
        r = randint(0, len(ser)-1)
        t = time()
        ser[r]
        pandas_time += time() - t

        t = time()
        lst[r]
        list_time += time() - t

    print(pandas_time, list_time)
```

The results (10 trials of indexing random elements 100000 times):

```
Pandas             Regular List
0.6404812335968018 0.03125190734863281
0.6560468673706055 0.0
0.5779874324798584 0.01562190055847168
0.5467743873596191 0.015621662139892578
0.6106545925140381 0.004016399383544922
0.5866603851318359 0.029597759246826172
0.7981059551239014 0.016004562377929688
0.8128316402435303 0.013040542602539062
0.5566465854644775 0.021578073501586914
0.6386256217956543 0.00500178337097168
```

Indexing a pandas series seems to be 30 - 100 times slower than a python list. Why? How can we speed this up?

Comment: because pandas is optimized to index *many values in a vectorized fashion*, not single values like a list. It also supports *index alignment*, which is often quite useful, but adds significant overhead compared to say, mere numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked `pandas'` source code. The `__getitem__` implementation in a pandas series has a lot of additional business logic compared to the regular python list, because the pandas series supports indexing with lists and iterables.

When indexing a pandas series the series:

1. Tries to apply the key if it is callable
2. Gets the value of the index at that key (sounds simple enough, but keep in mind the index is another pandas object that also has to support more than regular indexing)
3. Checks if 2) is scalar
4. If it's scalar return the result

These additional steps slow down the `__getitem__` dramatically compared to a regular python list.

To workaround this you can directly work with the underlying numpy array. Here we use `ser.values` to index instead:

```
ser = pd.Series(range(100))
lst = ser.tolist()

ser = ser.values

for _ in range(10):
    pandas_time = 0
    list_time = 0
    for _ in range(1000000):
        r = randint(0, len(ser)-1)
        t = time()
        ser[r]
        pandas_time += time() - t

        t = time()
        lst[r]
        list_time += time() - t

    print(pandas_time, list_time)
```

After indexing 1000000 random elements 10 times, we find that using `.values` is much faster than just indexing the pandas series but is still slower than using a python list

```
pd.Series.values    Regular List
0.18845057487487793 0.04786252975463867
0.10950899124145508 0.11034011840820312
0.048889875411987305 0.09512066841125488
0.17272686958312988 0.1406867504119873
0.14252233505249023 0.048066139221191406
0.06352949142456055 0.07906699180603027
0.1405477523803711 0.07815265655517578
0.18746685981750488 0.08007645606994629
0.1405184268951416 0.0781564712524414
0.07921838760375977 0.1412496566772461
```

To summarize using `.values` is the way to go when you need to quickly index a pandas Series. While it looks like `.tolist()` is faster, keep in mind that it will only be slightly faster when indexing individual elements. Numpy arrays will support much faster fancy indexing like indexing with multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

pandas's implementation of index and reindex is of low quality.
It contains too much overhead.

See the following link for futher discussion.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23735

Comment: Just a note for everyone: the linked GH issue #23735 now has been fixed (in pandas 1.5.0).