# Slow pandas Index lookup for unique index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to have a quick index lookup when using a pandas dataframe. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626058/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-non-unique-indexes-in-pandas) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489292/indexed-lookup-on-pandas-dataframe-why-so-slow-how-to-speed-up), I understand that I need to keep my index unique, otherwise all hope is lost.

I made sure that the index is sorted and unique:

```
df = df.sort_index()
assert df.index.is_unique
```

I measured the lookup speed:

```
%timeit df.at[tuple(q.values), 'column']
1000 loops, best of 3: 185 µs per loop
```

Then, when I moved the index to a separate python dictionary:

```
index = {}
for i in df.index:
  index[i] = np.random.randint(1000)
assert len(index) == len(df.index)
```

I got a huge speedup:

```
%timeit index[tuple(q.values)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.7 µs per loop
```

Why is it so? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to replicate python dict's speed (or something in <5x range) in a pandas index?

Comment: Interesting behaviour. My best guess is that a dataframe comes with a lot of baggage a dict has not. Also dataframe are not optimized for lookups but for matrix operations.

Comment: That makes sense to be an underlying issue, but still there's a question of how to disable the pandas overhead to get close to the performance of a dict. I am currently just placing a dict on top of pandas index, but surely someone would hit this problem before and merged the solution into pandas? Or is there an inherent reason that makes having a proper dict as an index impossible?

Comment: Note that your comparison is not fair, because you are supporting a single method of indexing. Also, you are not using the index to collect the item in Pandas.
In either case, as @above_c_level has gussed, this is caused by the Pandas overhead (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53997425/1397843)). You may want to move your data to Numpy `array` or Python `List` to get to the speed you like.